# Mongodb apply sort to lookup results if foreign key in array

Tags: mongodb

If I have a `client` and `task` collection

`task`

```
{
    fields: {
        client: [
            {
                uuid: 'b5050bf2-ca75-4b0a-920c-628ca45f929a',
            }
        ],
        uuid: '35c0541d-dd39-420b-9f74-027a9a268f88',
    }
}
```

`client`

```
{
    updated_at: ISODate('2024-03-18T12:07:17.313Z'),
    fields: {
        uuid: 'b5050bf2-ca75-4b0a-920c-628ca45f929a',
    }
}
```

How can I list all tasks with their latest client? I have code, but it does not return client data in `related_client` field

```
list_of_conditions = [
        {'$sort': {'updated_at': pymongo.DESCENDING}},
        {'$group': {'_id': '$fields.uuid', 'doc': {'$first': '$$ROOT'}}},
        {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$doc'}},
        {'$match':
            {
                'fields.uuid': {'$in': list(tasks_uuids)},
            },
            },
        {'$lookup':
            {
                'from': 'client',
                'let': {'client_uuid': '$fields.uuid'},
                'pipeline': [
                    {'$match': {'$expr': {'$eq': ['$fields.client.uuid', '$$client_uuid']}}},
                    {'$sort': {'updated_at': -1}},
                    {'$limit': 1}
                ],
                'as': 'related_client',
            },
        },
    ]
collection = await mongo_uow.task_actions.get_db_collection()  # task collection
collection_objects = collection.aggregate(list_of_conditions)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. **1.** Format your code/indentation properly. In the `task` example, `uuid` does not look like it's under `fields` and you're missing a closing `}`. So one has to assume that it is within `fields`, based on your pipeline. **2.** Provide more test data, so that there is more than one client and we can see what _latest client_ should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your lookup on `client` has `"client_uuid": "$fields.uuid"` but it should be `$fields.client.uuid`

   - When you do the `let`, it still refers to the field in the *base collection* you're running the aggregate from, so `task`.
2. In the `$match` part of the lookup, you're *in* the `client` collection, so there `{'$expr': {'$eq': ['$fields.client.uuid', '$$client_uuid']}}` should be `$fields.uuid`.

   - you've flipped the field you're trying to refer to in the `let` & `lookup`, which is why it doesn't match.
3. In the `task` collection, `"$fields.client.uuid"` is an array, so you can't do an equality match for 'uuid & array-of-uuids'. Use the `$in` operator.
4. Btw, your first stage is `{'$sort': {'updated_at': pymongo.DESCENDING}}` but there's no `update_at` field in tasks, only in `client.

With the fixes from notes 1 to 3, and ignoring the first-sort-stage, the lookup should be:

```js
db.task.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "updated_at": -1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$fields.uuid",
      "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } },
  {
    "$match": {
      "fields.uuid": {
        // this is hard-coded here, to have a working example
        "$in": [ "35c0541d-dd39-420b-9f74-027a9a268f88" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "client",
      "let": {
        "client_uuid": "$fields.client.uuid"  // fixed
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [  // fixed
                "$fields.uuid",  // fixed
                "$$client_uuid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        { "$sort": { "updated_at": -1 } },
        { "$limit": 1 }
      ],
      "as": "related_client"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zsmaZb8EOX-)

Result:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "fields": {
      "client": [
        {
          "uuid": "b5050bf2-ca75-4b0a-920c-628ca45f929a"
        }
      ],
      "uuid": "35c0541d-dd39-420b-9f74-027a9a268f88"
    },
    "related_client": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "fields": {
          "uuid": "b5050bf2-ca75-4b0a-920c-628ca45f929a"
        },
        "updated_at": ISODate("2024-03-18T12:07:17.313Z")
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here's what it would *probably* be in your Python code:

```py
list_of_conditions = [
        {'$sort': {'updated_at': pymongo.DESCENDING}},
        {'$group': {'_id': '$fields.uuid', 'doc': {'$first': '$$ROOT'}}},
        {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$doc'}},
        {'$match':
            {
                'fields.uuid': {'$in': list(tasks_uuids)},
            },
        },
        {'$lookup':
            {
                'from': 'client',
                'let': {'client_uuid': '$fields.client.uuid'},
                'pipeline': [
                    {"$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$in": ["$fields.uuid", "$$client_uuid"]
                        }
                    }},
                    {'$sort': {'updated_at': -1}},
                    {'$limit': 1}
                ],
                'as': 'related_client',
            },
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot! Got a problem in the case where client is null but solved it with this if statement
`"let": {
     "client_uuid": {
         "$cond": {
             "if": {
                 "$ne": [
                     "$fields.client",
                     None
                  ]
              },
              "then": f"$fields.client.uuid",
              "else": []
          }
      }
  },`